# numpy convert array of strings to integers or boolean (for masking)

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm new to Python and I'm challenged with converting an array of strings to numbers. 
My data was extracted from a larger data set of numbers and strings. It looks like:

```
array([b'Single', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'Single', b'Single',
b'', b'Single', ...])
```

I would like to use this data to create a mask, basically if 'Single' exists I would like to have a False or 0, so that I can mask the original data set. I don't know why there are b's there.

I've found similar questions answered but not string-to-number or string-to-boolean, only the reverse or converting a "string of numbers" to an integer.

My closest solution is something like:

```
np.where(modMask = 'Single' [False, True])
```

But then I get the error:

```
TypeError                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-64-4ad8a8f10b9b> in <module>()
----> 1 np.where(modMask = 'Single' [False, True])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You can do `bool_array = a.astype(object) != 'Single'`, for example

Comment: `modMask != b'Single'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return not x == b'Single'

vfunc = np.vectorize(f)
x = np.array([b'Single', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'Single'])

result = vfunc(x)
```

where

```
result = [False  True  True  True  True False]
```